# Wheel position sensor for precise aiming at a stationary target

Tags: sensors

I asked a different question a while back that led me to realize the hardest part of my project, position sensing. I had an idea and wanted to know if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

Specifically, I was considering the idea of a wheel orientation sensor that essentially is a circular PCB with copper channels going out from the center like bicycle spokes. And depending on which channel(s) completes the circuit, I know at least within a small degree of error, which I can figure out with math/trig, what direction my robot is pointed. At that point I might use a fine tune algorithm to further point it, which should be easy. The idea is  to use this to orient a laser. I looked into potentiometers and I think the precision I need would cost way more than I'm willing to pay, if it even exists.

Two questions, am I reinventing the wheel? Is there some sensor I can buy that's already essentially this, and has a good amount of precision? If I design it myself, what are some good ways to sense which channel(s) are completing the circuit? I can think of various ways, but none are elegant and simple. (Edit - one way I dreamed up is a digital bus, with one value per-channel that gets sent to the bus if the channel completes. Not exactly sure how to design this off the top of my head but I think it's possible. I can design my own board and stuff if I need to)

This could be a really good solution for me, I think, because what I can do is use math to reduce the gearing to get more precision out of my sensor. In other words, if the sensor wheel spins a lot faster than the orientation wheel, I can use whatever ratio I want to increase the precision of the robot. This comes at the cost of more time spinning the motor of course, which is fine with me.

Can I make this work?

Edit: The precision I need is: as much as possible :). It's for a buddy's pool table as a ball placement device. I need to point at various 1mm spots about 3-5 feet away. I want no more than 2mm error, preferably 1mm.

Also, I am going to store and load positions of the robot, so this circular "wire potentiometer" (I guess that's a thing?) should help with that as well, especially if I can figure out an elegant solution to the channel detection problem.

Comment: What is "precise" ? Any idea of the change in angle to move 1" at 100 yards?

Comment: @SolarMike Answered with an edit, thanks for that, I should have been more precise with my question in the first place

Comment: So, how does your 1mm at 5 feet translate into an angle? +/- 5 degrees? 1 degree? 30 seconds? 4 seconds?

Comment: OK, my math is a little rusty, but the answer I came up with is (degrees): 0.02221896082497133662762253845753
(and yes, that's the correct order of magnitude)

Comment: So how big is your circular pcb and how many channels? What resolution will you get? Close to your 0.02 degree?

Comment: @SolarMike - no, almost certainly not, which is why I was going to use gear ratios instead to increase the precision. If I gear down 100:1 I think it's doable, because that would let me get away with 2-degree error in the sensor

Comment: Wheel **encoders** are available for ths same purpose. Some are copper, but most are optical.

Comment: @AJN MAGNETS!! Lol. Great suggestion, thanks, that looks like exactly what I need. You should make that an official answer

Comment: You mean an encoder?

Comment: @DKNguyen - I was looking into how digital calipers work, I'm thinking I should be able to do something similar, in combination with gearing and an encoder. If a cheap caliper can do sub millimeter precision, I should be able to do another order of magnitude somehow. Will take some experimentation.

Comment: A digital caliper use a capacitive linear encoder, though there are other kinds of linear encoders. But do not mistake cheap mass produced products for being easy to DIY. Mass produced products are able to invest many dollars into R&D and specialized equipment to do things and then spread out those costs over many many parts.

Comment: @DKNguyen that's definitely fair. My current thinking is this: when encoders were mentioned, originally I was thinking I would be measuring the spin rate at the input, which could lead to problems due to backlash in the gearbox. Then I realized I was being dumb... I can put a wheel encoder on the OUTPUT of the gearbox as well as the input. Between the two encoders I am hoping that I can get the accuracy I need with software/tuning.

Comment: Yeah you want the output.

Answer (score 0):

@AJN answered my question. I think a wheel encoder and gear ratios can get me the precision I need.

I can calibrate it by pointing it at a spot manually, and then use wheel encoders on two axes to detect the number of turns. This plus gear ratios and math should give me the precision I need to automatically position the laser. I'm excited about this idea, it's simple and doable.

If @AJN would like to post an answer for credit I will mark it.

Comment: Be aware that gears exhibit [backlash](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/backlash#:~:text=Backlash%20refers%20to%20the%20angle,avoid%20jamming%20when%20they%20mesh.).

Comment: @Transistor - thanks, yeah, I need good gearing most likely. I'll figure out in the POC if it works or not, I can measure the output using string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Current drone technology appears to have this problem well sorted.  It includes motion sensors and GPS.  You should be able to find a package solution in that rabbit-hole.
PS 1" @ 100yards is approximately 1 minute of angle.

Comment: Hmm, are there any packages you can recommend? I've looked around a bit but I probably don't know what to be looking for. I'm open to the idea for sure though, anything to save a lot of work of designing my own thing.